# Nginx secure link issue

Tags: nginx

I have setup nginx Secure link successfully.

My Requirement, How can I pass sub-request once initial request passed ?

Problem, When I hit the secure link in browser, initial request comes with 200 status code. But subsequent requests are come with "403" status code.

Instead of appending the secure link URI to subsequent request , is there any way to handle it via adding some header ?.

```
10.11.12.14 - - [24/Nov/2015:15:34:21 +0000] "GET /client1/?md5=BP16QzCYd-vfY7JSU2Pg1e HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "-"
10.11.12.14 - - [24/Nov/2015:15:34:21 +0000] "GET /client1/styles/main.css?_b=7601 HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "http://10.11.12.13/client1/?md5=BP16QzCYd-vfY7JSU2Pg1e" "-"
10.11.12.14 - - [24/Nov/2015:15:34:21 +0000] "GET /client1/images/initial_load.gif HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "http://10.11.12.13/client1/?md5=BP16QzCYd-vfY7JSU2Pg1e" "-"
10.11.12.14 - - [24/Nov/2015:15:34:21 +0000] "GET /client1/require.config.js?_b=7601 HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "http://10.11.12.13/client1/?md5=BP16QzCYd-vfY7JSU2Pg1e" "-"
10.11.12.14 - - [24/Nov/2015:15:34:21 +0000] "GET /client1/bower_components/requirejs/require.js?_b=7601 HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "http://10.11.12.13/client1/?md5=BP16QzCYd-vfY7JSU2Pg1e" "-"
10.11.12.14 - - [24/Nov/2015:15:34:22 +0000] "GET /client1/styles/theme/elk.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "-"
```

Server Config Block:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-error.log;
        location /client1 {

        secure_link $arg_md5;
        secure_link_md5 "$remote_addr";
         if ($secure_link = "") {
                 return 403;
        }
    rewrite ^ /;
      }
     location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use secure link for static content.

Comment: Ok, Could you please share some idea how can I achieve it ?. Is there any work around solution available  ?.

Comment: I don't see your config. For me simples way is to place static assets into separate directory and don't use secure link for that directory

Comment: I have updated my server config block. Kindly assist